# Does caching to save memory make sense in face of swapping by the OS?

Tags: caching, memory-management, user-interface, swap, multimedia

*Disclaimer: I know very little about memory management or performance, and I code in C#.*

### Question:

Does "caching" medium-sized data (in the order of, say, dozens of MBs), especially **media** that will be **sent at any time to a device** (audio and images), on disk (instead of "keeping it in (virtual) memory"), in face of the fact that any OS will swap (maybe "page" is the correct word) unused memory to disk?

This may not have been clear, so I'll post examples.
*It is mainly related to **user interfaces, not network I/O***.

### Examples of what I'm talking about:

- FooSlideshow app could store slides on disk instead of allocating virtual memory for them.
- BarGame could store sounds of different, numerous events on disk and load them for playing.
- BazRenderer could store bitmaps of the several layers in a composite image if they're not prone to constant changing (If only one layer changes, the rest just have to be read from disk).

### Examples of what *I'm not* talking about:

- FooPlayer caches a buffer of the song while it streams from the server.
- BarBrowser caches images because the user may visit the same page.

### Why I should care:

Because, let's say a slideshow, when shown fullscreen on a 1024x768 screen, with 32 bits/pixel, would spend **1024 * 768 * 32 bytes = 3 MiB** (**8 MiB** for an HD screen). So for a 10-slides slideshow, that would be **30-80 MiB** just to cache the images. A short song, converted to 16-bit sample 44.1 KHz (CD quality) would also weight that on average.

From my C# code (but it could be Java, Python, whatever), **should I care** about making a complex caching system to free memory whenever possible, **or should I trust the OS** to swap that out? (And, the result would be the same? One approach will be better than the other? Why?)